# Android - How to share an WebView control among different tabs?

Tags: html, android

I'm developing an android application based on HTML.
I made several tabs and put a WebView into each tabs to display the page.
Currently I want to use just single WebView instance for all tabs to support login/out feature.
I mean I need consistency of user's status during transition of each webpages in tabs.

Is it available to share an WebView in different tabs?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. why not just implement tabs within the WebView?

Comment: I wanna fix the tabs in absoulte position (bottom of screen). Is it possible to do same thing in WebView with HTML?

Comment: Sure that's possible with HTML, but that's another question already ;)